# Can we change Action Method name in ASP.NET MVC Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is two action method in controller with same name, i want to change this action name using attribute.

```
[HttpGet] 
public ActionResult Show()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Show(FormCollection frm)
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Sure. Just rename it. What is stopping you from that ?

Comment: I am new in asp.net mvc, so i don't know how to change action name in case same action name are use in cotroller for get and post request.

Comment: what is problem in this ?

Comment: just simple rename your `Action` name like this .. 
`[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult ShowPost()
{
    return View();
}`

Answer (score 21):

You can use ActionName attribute.

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Show")]
public ActionResult PostShow()
{
    // your code...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have the same name, but make sure that the method signature is different. To do that, you can simply add a parameter to your post method.

```
[HttpGet] 
public ActionResult Show()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Show(string name)
{
    return View();
}
```

Now when the Show form is submitted the input field with name value `name` will be submitted to the HttpPost action method.